# Google Sheets поиск значения в диапазоне

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть вот такая таблица, в ней 3 варианта доставки товара и сам тариф на основе веса товара:

- Если вес 0-99 то 320
- Если вес 100-109 то 3
- Если вес 110-119 то 2,9

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе хочу получить формулу куда могу ввести "Вес груза", "Вариант" и получить тариф на доставку
Пока на уме вот такая формула для каждого вариант

```
=IF(H3<А21;B21;IF(H3<А20;B20;IF(H3<А19;B19 ... )))
```

Но думаю есть и попроще вариант, может кто сможет подсказать? Или хотя бы как она называется чтобы самому загуглить

Comment: Попроще — это через макросы. Формулы вообще штука непростая и сложные вычисления через них делать — сильная трата времени.

Comment: Но тут вычисления простые, поэтому формулой оптимальнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что таблица, которую вы привели на скриншоте расположена в столбцах `A:D`. Вводимый вес вы будете указывать в ячейку `F3`, а Вариант в ячейку `G3`:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ИНДЕКС(QUERY(A2:D; "select B, C, D where A >= " & F3+1 & " order by A limit 1"; 0 ); G3); "-")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### UPD

Чтобы формула воспринимала дробные числа измените ее одним из следующих образов

*для обычного округления (до 0,5 в меньшую сторону, свыше 0,5 в большую):*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(A2:D; "select B, C, D where A >= " & ROUND(F3)+1 & " order by A limit 1"; 0 ); G3); "-")
```

*либо для округления всегда в большую сторону:*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY(A2:D; "select B, C, D where A >= " & ROUNDUP(F3)+1 & " order by A limit 1"; 0 ); G3); "-")
```

Comment: Чуток подправить надо: при весе от 180 до 190 тариф по второму варианту 25

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA так в том то и дело, что у автора вопроса идет округление в большую сторону, по этому я сделал `+1`, т.е. при `100-109` у него в задаче `3`, что соответствует строке напротив `110`

Comment: `Если вес 110-119 то 2,9`, при том что 110 -это 3... Нелогично Думаю, автор тут ошибся.

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA увы, таблица не моя )) понятно, что при правильной градации и формулы были бы короче, а если еще и в порядке увеличения, а не уменьшения веса - и того короче. Как, собственно, вы и предлагали автору

Comment: да это не важно если что подправлю)

Comment: @Leonid ну, в таком случае у вас как минимум есть несколько предложенных вариантов )) выбирайте любой

Comment: @ZxNuClear ваш хорошо подошел. Учитывает даже если число меньше 100 вводить)

Comment: @ZxNuClear только дробные числа почему то не считает

Comment: *Учитывает даже если число меньше 100 вводить* - и как это учитывает, если для диапазона от 0 до 99.99 в Вашей таблице нет тарифов? :)

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA `Если вес 0-99 то 320` - как и говорилось, не совсем логично составлена таблица

Comment: @Leonid дополнил ответ формулами, которые воспринимают дробные числа в том числе

Answer (score 1):

Любое количество строк, любое количество вариантов, любые размеры диапазонов веса:

```
=ИНДЕКС(B2:D21;ПОИСКПОЗ(F2;A2:A21;-1)+(СЧЁТЕСЛИ(A2:A21;F2)=0);G2)
```

На основе выбранного тарифа получаем стоимость доставки:

```
 =G4*F2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание. В столбце А значения веса должны располагаться строго по убыванию.

Если таблицу "перевернуть" - расположить вес в порядке возрастания, формула будет короче и шустрее:

```
=ИНДЕКС(B2:D21;ПОИСКПОЗ(F2;A2:A21;1);G2)
```

Если возможен вес <100, для корректной работы формулы в наименьшем диапазоне нужно добавить строку с нулевым значением веса о прописать в строке значения тарифов.